# jQuery: Add function self to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, self

Given a function, like so:

```
var allev = new Array();
function events(index) {
    allev[index] = $(this); // doesn't work
}
```

Is there any way to get this to work in the way above, or am I always restricted to:

```
var allev = new Array();
function events(index) {
    // ...
}

function() { // out of scope, so make objects global
    var count = allev.length;
    var inst = events(count);
    allev[count] = inst;
}
```

If there are any betters options than the two above, I'm open to those as well.

Comment: First off, when you call `$(this)`, as far as I can see, it doesn't refer to anything.

Comment: @Ken, `$(this)` is refering to `function events(index)`...

Comment: So you're trying to put a function into an array? O. o

Comment: @BrianGraham: `this` would be `window` unless you called it using `.call` or `.apply`.

Comment: It really isn't clear what the outer-scope of events is. Meaning, is events part of another object or simply wired-up to global scope.  If 'this' is a refereence to global-scope...then that is WHY it is failing.

Comment: @Rocket is right.  This is a function, not a method.  `this` will be the global object, or undefined in strict mode.

Comment: @BrianGraham: How is this being called, is it inside another scope, or is it global?

Comment: The second example doesn't put the function in the array.  It runs the function and pushes the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to look a little more into the jQuery API and I found [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). It does exactly what I want, without having a method pass itself to make `this` work properly.

```
allev[index] = $.proxy(function() { return this; }, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call functions (as opposed to methods) in JavaScript, `this` is the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode.  So using `this` like you have above will never work.

You *could* do this:

```
function events(index) {
    arr[index] = arguments.callee;
    alert("Hi");
}
```

but that will **break** if you ever use strict mode (which is actually a really good idea).

You could also do this:

```
function events(index) {
    allev[index] = this; // will work if you call with apply or call
}
```

If, and only if, you only ever call `events` like this:

```
events.call(events, 12);
```

`call` and `apply` both allow you to specify what `this` will be equal to inside of a function call.  The difference is that `call` expects all arguments to be listed out, while `apply` expects all arguments to be passed in an array.  So the above would be equivalent to

```
events.apply(events, [12]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7FW6R/)